# CSS 1px solid border appearing fuzzy in chrome

Tags: css

I'm trying to do a simple 1px white solid border in CSS however in Chrome the border appears slightly fuzzy and discoloured.

Here's what it looks like and what it should look like:[image]

Here is my CSS

```
.button {
    font-family: "BrooklynSamuels";
    font-size:30px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;    
    border: solid #ffffff;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;

}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="logo"></div>

    <div class="center-message">
    <div class="message-header">Our store is currently closed</div>
    <div class="message-content">But you can still pre-order for delivery</div>
    <div class="button">PRE-ORDER NOW</div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Could you add your HTML and make it a Stack Snippet, so we can reproduce the issue right here from your question? There is an editor button for it.

Comment: Also, I just noticed your `border` rule - can we actually omit the `border-width` when using the shorthand?  Try `border: 1px solid #fff` instead.

Comment: Have you zoomed the page?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález The zoom is set to 100%

Comment: @domdom I've changed it to `border: 1px solid #fff` but the issue still exists

Comment: Again, I'd appreciate if you could make it a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Also see [mcve].

Comment: Then, is your computer or browser using a DPI setting that will make a 1px item not fix exactly in a physical pixel? It feels like a subpixel rendering issue.

Comment: Add `margin:1px` to `button` and also use `border:1px solid #fff;`, Have you assign `body` `overflow:hidden` ?

Comment: Your button css is overwriting with some other css. Debug and verify.

Comment: Without a [mcve] and without further input, I'm going to flag this as *can't reproduce*. Everything looks fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/rktg2b7f/

Answer (score 0):

Not a very good "answer", but I did manage to (A) make the produce reproducible and (B) discover that it's related to the font call.

Duplicate of this code snippet can be found at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wnpdkwj1/).

Perhaps someone else can shed more light on WHY this is happening, and any workarounds other than NOT calling a different font?

```css
* {
   list-style-type:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
  
    /* uncommenting this font declaration causes the 1px borders to go "fuzzy" */
   /*font-family:"Century Gothic";*/
}
div#loginForm {
 border:3px double #000;
 border-radius:1em;
 padding:0.5em;
 background:#ccc;
}
div#loginForm > ul > li {
 padding:0 0.25em 0 0;
 margin:0.5em 1em;
 text-align:center;
 border:1px solid #000;
 background:#ccc;
}
div#loginForm > ul > li.act {
 background:#fff;
 border:1px solid #666;
}
div#loginForm > ul > li.act > label {
 color:#faa;
}

div#loginForm > ul > li > label {
 display:block;
 float:left;
 padding:0.125em 1em 0.125em 0.5em;
 margin:0.25em 0 0.25em 0.25em;
}
div#loginForm > ul > li input[type="text"],
div#loginForm > ul > li input[type="password"] {
 margin:0.5em 0.25em 0.25em 0;
 width:100%;
 padding:0.125em;
 background:inherit;
 color:#fff;
 letter-spacing:0.5px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 border:0;
 text-align:right;
}
div#loginForm > ul > li input[type="submit"] {
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding-top:1em;
 padding-bottom:1em;
 border:0;
 background:#1b242d;
 color:#fff;
}
div#loginForm > ul > li span {
 display:block;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
  <div id="loginForm">
   <ul>
    <li>
     <label for="email">email</label>
     <span><input type="text" name="email" id="email"  /></span>
     <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <label for="password">password</label>
     <span><input type="password" name="password" id="password"  /></span>
     <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <input type="submit" value="go" />
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```